# .htaccess friendly urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, server-side

I got a problem with my .htaccess I want to create a friendly url, I tried many ways esp. some of the ways are found on this site, but still it isn't working..

Heres my code:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -Indexes  
    Header unset ETag
    FileETag None

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteOptions Inherit
    RewriteRule .* index.php 

    #friendly urls
    RewriteRule ^styles/style.css$ /view/style.php
    RewriteRule ^styles/style.css$ view/style.php
```

Comment: Style.css isnt what most would consider friendly urls.

Comment: @Toby Allen so how to solve this???

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing exactly how it's not working for you I can see a big issue.

```
 RewriteRule .* index.php
```

That rule matches *anything*. So by the time you get down to your 'friendly urls' section, the url has changed to 'index.php' which of course doesn't match.

Move the catch-all line below your 'friendly urls' section and add `[L]` to each of your friendly url rewrite rules.

Comment: ok...I tried it and still its Object not found.. the fileoath is ww.domain.com/view/style.php and want to change to www.domain.com/styles.css

Comment: so the actual path of the file on the server is `/view/style.php`?

Comment: yeah.. and I tried may ways to make it work even changing the directory still doesn't work..\

Comment: I think you're missing the point of using `mod_rewrite`. Why are you trying to access `/view/style.php` directly? That will fail because the URL will be rewritten by the `.*` rule (the one that should go at the bottom). I suggest you use a [.htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) to see exactly what rules are being executed when you try to access a URL.